# &ytp-pause-overlay=0 no longer works

Tags: iframe, youtube

I am trying to get rid of the More Videos section on a you tube iframe player when you pause a video.  Everything I can see online says you need to add &ytp-pause-overlay=0 to the URL.  That does not do anything.   How do I get rid of that section when you pause a video.  It is hiding the exact thing I want my users to see.